# Angular Error in Console of the web browser

Tags: angular, laravel

working with Angular app with Laravel api. I have following html file as well,

```
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let emp of employees">
            <th scope="row">{{emp.id}}</th>
            <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.email}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.salary}}</td>

            
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

but I cant display my table data according to the html. and console generate following error message
`core.js:10105 NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'.`

how could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are importing the @angular/common module into your feature module. i.e. `import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';` then list the common module in the imports array

`@NgModule({ imports:[ CommonModule ]...})`

Comment: may I import this module in app.module.ts file?

Comment: Yes, but see more information about sharing modules here [Sharing NgModules](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules). Also, another important consideration is that Angular performs tree-shaking to remove unused source code and reduces the overall size of the application bundles so that the browser loads the application faster.

Comment: @KibéM.C - That would be just wrong. ebduhon gave the correct answer.